# Two images and one text paragrap (HTML+CSS)

Tags: position, css-float

I have this markup:

```
<body>

<img id="one" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" />

<p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla,
orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim.
Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.</p>

<img id="two" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" />

</body>
```

How can I make them to be in the beginning left-top (img id="one") and at the end right-bottom (img id="two") of the paragraph and nicely wrap around with its text?

See http://jsfiddle.net/ge15jLfg/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Align left for the top image and you can use divs for the bottom one. It is a bit tricky as you have to know the length of the text or play with a bit of javascript.

See here:http://jsfiddle.net/ge15jLfg/1/

```
<img id="one" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" align="left"/>

<div style="float: right; width: 0px; height: 200px"></div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right">
    <img id="two" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract"/>
</div>

<p>

    Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla,
    orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim.
    Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.
Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla,
    orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim.
    Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.
Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla,
    orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim.
    Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.

</p>
```